# Wait for a job for a certain timespan

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to dispatch a job to the queue and wait for it to finish, but only for a certain timespan (e.g. 10 seconds). If it does not finish in that timespan I want to do A, otherwise B.

How can this be accomplished? The only way I have seen is using events or the Queue triggers, but there seems to be no uniform way of checking if a certain job is finished.

Maybe I'm just blind and there is an easy solution, but I'm looking forward to your replies.

Answer (score -1):

try this may it will help you 
in your controller

```
use Carbon/Carbon;

public function yourmethodname (){
  if(carbon::now()<=carbon::now()->addHours(2){
  //dispatch a job to the queue
   }else{
  //do whatever you want here
  }
}
```

you can add any time day or month in above carbon::now method for eg to add month carbon::now()->addMonths(whatever)
hope this will help you

Comment: This is useless, since this will always dispatch the job to the queue...

Comment: @stu its just demo to show you . yes it will always dispatch job because i m comparing with carbon::now, if you have time saved in database than you can use that  time for eg:- if($datatabletimecolumn<=carbon::now()->addHours(2) moreover time column you can also add in jobdispatcher table which is provided by laravel by default